# What does this do: git branch -f

Tags: git, branch

I'm trying to figure out how to use this command properly. I believe this is the command and flag I want to essentially make one branch into my other branch (basically delete a branch and create a new branch with the same name with the files of another branch), but I don't know for sure, or if I have the syntax correct.

If I do this:

```
git branch -f master sub-branch
```

Will it remove all of the files from master and fill it with the files from sub-branch?

Comment: When you move a branch there's no moving of files - all the branches are just pointers to a particular commit. This command moves the `master` pointer to the `sub-branch` pointer. Titas has the correct answer but you might want to read up on [What a branch is](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is), especially starting from Figure 3.4.

Comment: @Nick Oh. Thank you so much for the explanation and resource. I'm obviously still very new to git, so this is a huge help.

Comment: No problem. Git can be a confusing beast but it helps if you can visualise the "tree" of commits and the branches and things pointing at them. That whole online book is fairly readable so stick it in your bookmarks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `-f` argument stands for `--force`.

- If a branch called `master` already exists, git will not allow you to overwrite it, unless you use `-f`.
- Second parameter (`sub-branch`) will be used to determine where the `master` branch's `HEAD` should be pointing to.

Comment: The effect of "git branch -f master <commitId>" will be the same as "git reset --soft HEAD~<counter until commitId>" ?

Comment: What happens to the old branch? Is this grafted on top, or is it deleted, or is a duplicate name?

Comment: @noelicus this edits the branch to point to a new commit, retaining the branch's push/pull targets. The old commits are still accessible via reflog.

Comment: In my case, there is one scenario where command is "git branch -f branchname" is given. So what will happen in that case?