# How to abandon old Git Master, and use branch as new master?

Tags: git

We have a project where we at one time had to go back in Git history a bit and start a new branch (which we here will call "new_branch") from an old commit. Now, all development is happening in new_branch, and the old Master is useless after the point where the branch was made. So now we have a situation that looks like this:

```
C1 = Commit 1, C2 = Commit 2, etc.

            C1                       
             |                       
            C2                       
             |\                      
            C3 \                     
             |  \                    
            ...  \                   
             |    \                  
Master -->  C17    \                         
                    \                
                   C18               
                    |                        
                   ...               
                    |                
                   C37 <-- new_branch
```

So what I want to do now, is abandon (undo?) all the commits made in Master after the branching-off point, that is, C3 through C17. At least, that's what I *think* I want to do? I mean, C3 through C17 are useless now, and if I could undo them then I can merge new_branch back into Master, to make Master useful again.

So my question is, is this the right approach to achieve my goal of being able to use Master again? And which command (I use Git from the command line in Linux) should I use to undo the C3 through C17 commits? This is a project for work, so it's very important that I get this right.

Comment: delete master, rename new_branch to master

Comment: Are you saying that all commits from C3 to C17 are to be abandoned?

Comment: Yes, C3 through C17 happened 7 weeks ago, and ended in a dead end. We've long since moved on.

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward solution is simply to force push `new_branch` onto origin's `master`:

```
git checkout new_branch
git push -f master
```

Then fixup your local `master` in one of several ways:

1. `git reset --hard origin/master` (*on* branch `master`)
2. `git branch -D master` (*not on* branch `master`, pull again to get the updated one)

There's no need in this scenario to rebase existing `master` with the `new_branch`.

This will (obviously) obliterate the existing `master` and replace it with the contents and history of `new_branch`. *Be sure of your intent.*

---

As Romain points out below, using [`git branch -f`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609698/what-does-this-do-git-branch-f) obviates the local fixup step:

```
git branch -f master new_branch && git push -f origin master
```

since it moves the branch pointer locally as well.

---

As with many git issues, there are many ways to solve this, and other answers may be just as viable.

Comment: This is the undeniable appeal of being very simple. Thanks a lot. I may well end up doing this, unless someone gives me an even better suggestion.

Comment: @Enfors Pleasure. Do wait to see what other answers come in, there are always several ways of fixing git issues, with different workflows having different advantages. If you accept it I'll (happily) know it worked for you!

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a variant for brevity (from master branch) : `git branch -f master new_branch && git push -f origin master`. Just to give an alternative way of achieving the same solution (but the idea is the same so it didn't deserve a full blown answer)

Comment: Hey again @RomainValeri! git tag team ;) (pun intended)

Comment: @RomainValeri I like your approach, because that means doing things locally (`git branch -f master new_branch`) so I can validate that everything looks good, *before* I do the push - right?

Comment: @Endors Yes, that's the main reason I tend to proceed this way. One command to set it right locally, one to reflect the operation on remote server.

Comment: @RomainValeri Feel free to post a new answer, it's technically a different workflow. I'll roll back this one if you do.

Comment: @msanford I considered it a moment at first, but no worries, I feel it's quite clear like you presented it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two general approaches to doing this; each has drawbacks, so it depends what's more important in your situation.  Each approach has variations as well, with smaller trade-offs...

---

The first approach is a history rewrite of `master`.  That simply means moving `master` in a way that removes from its history some commits that currently are part of its history.

Any history rewrite has certain costs no matter how you do it - so it's usually best to do it the simplest way that meets your requirements.  In this case, that's probably

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard new_branch
git push --force-with-lease
```

This is similar in effect to the approach msanford recommends, but has two advantages.  First, it's a little more concise (in that it updates the local branch first and uses that as the setup for updating the rmeote).  Secondly, replacing `-f` with `--force-with-lease` provides a little extra safety, in that it ensures the remote hasn't had anything new committed to it that you're unaware of.  (In your specific case, that probably isn't much of an issue; but it's a really good habit to get into.)

The cost of a history rewrite of a branch that has been shared across repos (i.e. `push`ed, and then - at least potentially - `fetch`ed or `pull`ed into other repos) is that other repos sharing the branch will see the branch move in an "unexpected" way and will have to recover.  The recovery procedure is documented in the `git rebase` docs, in the section "recovering from upstream rebase".  It is important to coordinate with the entire team when doing this, as if any team member does the wrong thing when recovering, it can undo the history rewrite.

The upside is that you end with a very nice history that doesn't show the removed commits at all.  (Beware, though, that if those commits have been shared, nothing you can do ensures that they're "gone forever".  If they contain sensitive information, that's a bigger problem and the information basically has to be considered compromised - though there are steps you can take to at least try to prevent further spread of such info.)

So if you can practically coordinate with all users of the repo, this is a good way to go.  But if you can't, there's another way.

---

The second approach is to undo the changes on master - i.e. revert it back to `C2` - and then merge `new_branch` in.  This conforms to the way branches are "supposed to" usually move, so doesn't carry the costs of a rewrite.  But, it means that the abandoned commits (and their reversal) remain forever in history.

```
git checkout master
git revert -n C3..HEAD
git commit
git merge new_branch
```

This gives you a history like

```
C1 - C2 - C3 - ... - C17 - R -- M <--(master)
       \                       /
        C18 - ........... - C37 <--(new_branch)
```

`R` makes `master` look as it did at `C2`, and `M` is a simple merge of the newer changes over that.

If you omit the `-n` option from the `revert` command, you can skip the `commit` command, but you'll get a separate commit to undo each commit from `C3` to `C17`.  There are also techniques for embedding the undoing-of-changes in the merge commit itself if you really feel strongly that this is better, but it creates an "evil merge" - a merge that hides changes and may confuse both users and certain future operations like `git rebase`.

The downside is a messier history.  (If you really need the history to document how you got where you are, then it is arguably more accurate; but it is certainly more complicated and shows information you may no longer need.  It's certainly not suitable if the reverted commits contain sensitive information that you don't want to keep spreading.)

But, as noted above, it follows normal branch movement patterns, so avoids the costs of a history rewrite.

So again, it depends what's more important in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to erase c3 - c17 you can checkout c3 and then put your new branch's changes on top of that using merge. Then if you push back up to master then c3 - c17 will be gone

Comment: What would be the point of the merge?  Since it's on top of a detached HEAD state, and so will not automatically be incorporated into `master`, the push will have to be forced / will be a history rewrite; which means you might as well forgo the merge and just force push from the newer branch

Comment: but you said you wanted both the new branches code and the c2. Youll have to combine those somehow, ie merge? I mean or you could rebase or do it manually, but however you want to do it, its your project

Comment: Ok.... first, I'm not OP, so I said nothing of the sort.  Second, C2 is already "in" `new_branch`